# Woocommerce Subscriptions: Do some code when a renewal using debit direct occurs

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-subscriptions

I have an woocommerce website using the plugin "Woocommerce Subscriptions". In the payment options for subscriptions i have two methods to renew the subscription automatically:

- Stripe (using the card data associated in the first checkout of the subscription)
- Stripe SEPA (debit direct)

I followed the woocommerce documentation ( https://woocommerce.com/document/subscriptions/develop/payment-gateway-integration/ ) and ended trying the following hooks to add the custom code when the renewals of the subscriptions that use these methods occurs. But i have not been successful. The hooks are not triggering. The payment gateways are correct, i guess. Can someone point me what am i doing wrong?

```
add_action('woocommerce_scheduled_subscription_payment_stripe_sepa','scheduled_subscription_payment', 10, 3);
add_action('woocommerce_scheduled_subscription_payment_stripe','scheduled_subscription_payment', 10, 3);

function scheduled_subscription_payment( $amount_to_charge, $renewal_order ) {
//enter here when the renewal of the subscription is successful and do the custom code
}
```